# Center floated div items

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have:

```css
#content {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="item"><img /><br />wordsn</div>
  <div class="item"><img /><br />stuff</div>
  <div class="item"><img /><br />asdasdasdn</div>
  <div class="item"><img /><br />Dhdfrhwon</div>
  <div class="item"><img /><br />sewfafdion</div>
</div>
```

I want to center these images items in the div, and have them float next to each other, and have it wrap nicely.

I have tried everything and it works in IE and breaks in Firefox so I hack some more crap and then it breaks in IE.

Answer (score 2):

```
.item { width: 400px; margin: auto 0; }
```

You need to specify a width so it can calculate the appropriate margins.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `float` and start using `display: inline` for the `item` divs.

Then you can give `content` a `text-align: center` - should work.

By the way, semantically, a structure like this might work better - depending on what those divs represent, of course.

```
<ul id="content">
    <li><img />wordsn</li>
    <li><img />stuff</li>
    <li><img />asdasdasdn</li>
    <li><img />Dhdfrhwon</li>
    <li><img />sewfafdion</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this solution does not work even tho it seems like it should.  I tried inline-block (which is closer to what is needed) and such which IE doesn't work.  This is a very tricky problem I have tried many things.

Comment: @Mohamed then I don't understand your question completely - I'm using this method all over and it works fine. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I want many per row this is only giving only 1 or not centering depending on how I mix up

Comment: @Mohamed sorry, I overlooked the `<br>` s. Get rid of them and it will work.

Comment: I mean it is not working across browsers too, I think if can make inline-block in IE6 will work

Comment: the plain inline was not working in some older browsers and even newer for wierd reason

Comment: @Mohamed I think that is solvable but anyway, you seem to have a working solution so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is what I got to work across all browsers:

```
#content {
text-align:center;
}

.item {
     display: -moz-inline-box;
    display:inline-block;
}

* html .item { display:inline; }  /* for IE 6? */
* + html .item { display:inline; }  /* for IE 7? */
```

edit: width not required

Comment: I still think this could be solved using a simple `display: inline` for all browsers - if the items don't have to have a fixed width. But if this works for you in all browsers, all right!

Comment: wait no, width required for IE6.  god damn.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you are trying to achieve? (you will need to resize the page to see the wrap effect)

[djgdesign.co.uk](http://djgdesign.co.uk/portfolio.php?cat=2)

Answer (score 0):

```
#content .item{width:200px;margin:0 auto}
```